# Decompiler loop nesting order and code gen ordering

Tags: graph, graph-theory, decompiler

After obtaining "natural loops" from a control flow diagram of basic blocks. How can these loops be ordered from inner most to outer most? I.e the inner most loop contains no other loops?

I obtained the loops using the dominator method, see the slide titled "Identifying Natural Loops with Dominators" here: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~mstrout/CS553Fall07/Slides/lecture15-control.pdf

Additionally what algorithm should be used to traverse the control flow graph such that writing out each node would yield the correct output code?

Answer (score 2):

In a well structured program (i.e. no gotos), the beginning of a loop must dominate the contents of the loop.

Every node which has incoming backedges must be the head of a loop. However, you have some freedom to the actual loop contents thanks to the ability to specify explicit `continue`s. The minimal set of nodes that must be in the loop are all blocks that have a backedge to the head and all blocks which are reverse reachable from them and dominated by the head. The maximal set of nodes that can be in the loop is of course just all nodes dominated by the head.

Nesting is determined by whether the head of one loop is in the contents of another loop. In some cases, you have the freedom to decide whether to place the loop inside the outer loop or not.

Comment: "Nesting is determined by whether the head of one loop is in the contents of another loop" But what if we have 3 nested loops A,B and C, if we check A we'll find it contains B and C, but the proper order is that A only contains B, and C only contains C?

Comment: @paulm What do you mean by proper order?

Comment: If the algorithm said add any loop as a nested loop if its head block is within my basic blocks, then B C would appear as children of A because their heads are within A? But C's head is also within B, so really C should be B's child, not A's child?

Comment: If C is within B and B is within A, then obviously C is within A. You can find the direct children instead with slight modification if you want.